# Transient Fault Rate for Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, transient-failure

The company I am working for uses Azure Blob Storage for our filesystem and we have found that there is a very high rate of failure because of Connection Refused:

[image: Connection Refused]

On our main PHP application running laravel in swoole we have seen 8 of these errors in the last day.   And on one long running that required handling about 1000 files it failed twice in a row.

So I would estimate that the failure rate for azureBlob storage is about 0.1 -> 1 %

For the connection we are using:
"name": "league/flysystem-azure-blob-storage",
"version": "1.0.0",

With the retry middleware:
"microsoft/azure-storage-blob": "1.1",
"microsoft/azure-storage-common": "1.5.1",

And guzzle:
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "7.3.0",

We create the provider with this code:

```
class AzureBlobStorageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider { 
/** * Bootstrap services. * * @return void */ 
public function boot() {
   Storage::extend('azure', function ($app, $config) { $client =      
BlobRestProxy::createBlobService( "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={$config['name']};AccountKey={$config['key']};" );    

 $retryMiddleware = RetryMiddlewareFactory::create(
            RetryMiddlewareFactory::GENERAL_RETRY_TYPE,  // Specifies the retry logic
            10,  // Number of retries
            1000,  // Interval
            RetryMiddlewareFactory::EXPONENTIAL_INTERVAL_ACCUMULATION,  // How to increase the wait interval
            true  // Whether to retry connection failures too, default false
        );

        $client->pushMiddleware($retryMiddleware);

        $adapter = new AzureBlobStorageAdapter($client, $config['container']);
        //$cachedAdapter = new CachedAdapter($adapter, new PredisStore(Redis::client()));
        return new Filesystem($adapter, new Config([
            'disable_asserts' => true,
        ]));
    });
}

/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Get the services provided by the provider.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function provides()
{
    return [Filesystem::class];
}}`
```

Does anyone have any ideas what we can do to prevent ConnectionRefused Errors or handle them better?

### The full error:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException cURL error 7: Failed to connect to sonarprodblob01.blob.core.windows.net port 443: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://sonarprodblob01.blob.core.windows.net/sonar-prod-blob-01/monitoring_results/ffda21bb-ca8f-4e02-aa5a-93886155271b 
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:210 GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:158 GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:110 GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php:236 GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler::processMessages
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php:168 GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler::tick
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php:183 GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler::execute
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:248 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::invokeWaitFn
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:224 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::waitIfPending
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:269 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::invokeWaitList
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:226 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::waitIfPending
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:62 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::wait
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/microsoft/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php:3018 MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy::getBlobProperties
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/league/flysystem-azure-blob-storage/src/AzureBlobStorageAdapter.php:240 League\Flysystem\AzureBlobStorage\AzureBlobStorageAdapter::getMetadata
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/league/flysystem-azure-blob-storage/src/AzureBlobStorageAdapter.php:153 League\Flysystem\AzureBlobStorage\AzureBlobStorageAdapter::has
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Filesystem.php:58 League\Flysystem\Filesystem::has
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Filesystem.php:99 League\Flysystem\Filesystem::put
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php:249 Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter::put
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php:398 Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager::__call
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:261 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic
    Http/Controllers/PollerEndpointController.php:98 Sonar\Http\Controllers\PollerEndpointController::getSnmpResults
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54 Illuminate\Routing\Controller::callAction
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher::dispatch
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:254 Illuminate\Routing\Route::runController
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:197 Illuminate\Routing\Route::run
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:695 Illuminate\Routing\Router::Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:128 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    Http/Middleware/PollerMiddleware.php:49 Sonar\Http\Middleware\PollerMiddleware::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:50 Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php:31 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php:40 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::then
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:697 Illuminate\Routing\Router::runRouteWithinStack
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:672 Illuminate\Routing\Router::runRoute
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:636 Illuminate\Routing\Router::dispatchToRoute
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:625 Illuminate\Routing\Router::dispatch
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:166 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel::Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:128 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/ServeNova.php:27 Laravel\Nova\Http\Middleware\ServeNova::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php:86 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    Http/Middleware/BlockRepeatedAuthenticationFailuresMiddleware.php:25 Sonar\Http\Middleware\BlockRepeatedAuthenticationFailuresMiddleware::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    Http/Middleware/MultiTenant.php:65 Sonar\Http\Middleware\MultiTenant::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:57 Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::then
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:141 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel::sendRequestThroughRouter
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:110 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel::handle
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/swooletw/laravel-swoole/src/Server/Sandbox.php:257 SwooleTW\Http\Server\Sandbox::handleRequest
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/swooletw/laravel-swoole/src/Server/Sandbox.php:217 SwooleTW\Http\Server\Sandbox::prepareObResponse
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/swooletw/laravel-swoole/src/Server/Sandbox.php:179 SwooleTW\Http\Server\Sandbox::run
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/swooletw/laravel-swoole/src/Server/Manager.php:225 SwooleTW\Http\Server\Manager::onRequest
    /usr/share/sonar/vendor/upscale/swoole-blackfire/src/ProfilerDecorator.php:54 [main]
```

Comment: Please post the error message as text and not as image.

Comment: @WrichikBasu added tjhe exception

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have implemented Rate Limiting process, it still requires transientfault handling.

Properly implementing a rate limiting mechanism in your application will substantially reduce the number of transient faults.

Transient faults can occur for reasons other than TooManyRequests

Reference Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/rate-limiting-requests#transient-fault-handling